# Writing my own MySQL Library? Is it a good idea?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Update: Thanks for all the help guys, I've decided to try and write my own PHP class for handling MySQL requests.**

I'm faced with a problem right now when I'm trying to make the switch from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` functions, in that I have literally tens of thousands of lines of PHP/MySQL code and queries scattered across hundreds of files, and they're all using functions such as `mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows`, `mysql_fetch_assoc`, etc. Going through and changing these line by line (even with find/replace) to `mysqli_` functions with prepared statements and all is pain enough, but what if in the future PHP.net decides to release something else that will deprecate the `mysqli_` functions?

So right now I'm considering perhaps writing my own MySQL library (is that what you would call it?) that calls the `mysqli_` functions and including it in all my files. This way, if I needed to change something else in the future, theoretically I could change the function in my "library" once and changes would be reflected on all pages, instead of manually going through and changing everything by hand.

Would this be a good idea? I found something online called [MeekroDB](http://www.meekro.com/), but first of all I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for and second of all they're charging $50 to use this commercially (which I want to do.) Are there other free solutions, or would I just be wasting my time?

Any comments/feedback is appreciated :)

**Edit:** In case this wasn't clear, it's not as if I'm making a connection to my database in every file that I'm making queries to database. I have a functions.php file that I use to connect to the MySQL database and I `include` that file in all my other files. My question is more related to functions such as `mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows`, and `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: The problem here is that you have your database code "scattered across hundreds of files".  You need to refactor to avoid that.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean, I have a functions.php I'm including with all the functions I wrote myself and my database connection in that file, but how would I prevent making a `mysql_query` in separate files, or using `mysql_fetch_assoc` in a file that I need it?

Comment: You can avoid that by abstracting away the database logic from your modules and using them on a "higher level". I would highly recommend looking into PHP frameworks like Zend, Laravel or CodeIgniter! They help you avoid this.

Comment: Really you should not be adding the mysql_* functions to new code, in the next version 5.5 they will be officially deprecated, and possible removed completely in version 5.6.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm referring to the code I wrote for my websites maybe 3 or 4 years ago. I'm using `mysqli_` in all new code that I write.

Comment: Think [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_\(Java\)) ; it's Java, but that's the kind of principles you want in your PHP lib (probably simpler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at your referenced link to `MeekroDB`, I don't think what you're writing is a MySQL API like the `mysql_*`/`mysqli_*` methods.

What you're in fact looking to write is a *Database Abstraction Layer*, despite it being specific to MySQL.

The fact is, unless you're going to write your own underlying module to communicate with MySQL (of course, you could also do this *with difficulty* in PHP), you're probably going to end up using the `mysqli_` methods as a backing anyway.

There are many of these layers available, but I'd honestly consider using PDO over writing your own, or using `mysqli_*` if you're worried about functions being deprecated. PDO uses its own MySQL driver, and so will be updated if it needs to be. It also supports all what you'd require including easy-to-use transactions, prepared statements and whatnot.

If you wanted to create your own easy-access methods such as `DB::Query(..)`, you can do this by wrapping PDO easy enough.

Overall, though, I don't see how this is going to help with organising your code. You're probably going to want to look into something like an ORM (Object Relationship Mapper) to your DB where you can define your own classes that map straight into tables, which should alleviate the need of running queries almost entirely, apart from edge cases. The most comprehensive ORM available would probably be [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), although you can quite easily write your own by again, wrapping PDO.

Just as an example of what you could achieve by using an ORM, here's a snippet of code to demonstrate:

```
$blogPost = BlogPosts::Load(123);
$blogPost->title = 'New Title';
$blogPost->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping your code around the basic PHP database function is a good idea, otherwise there are already a few good solutions you should not have to build you own library. Maybe ORM (Object-relational_mapping) would be interesting for you, popular libraries are [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [propel](http://propelorm.org/).

Answer (score 2):

> Would this be a good idea?

As a matter of fact, this is the **only** sane way of handling SQL queries.

Let me suggest you my [library, designed to protect your queries against SQL injections](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php). It is absolutely free and  way better than anything that costs $50 or $5000.

The only thing you need to learn before starting to use it is *type-hinted placeholders*, but the conception is very easy and I am sure you will get it in a second. Nevertheless, feel free to ask any questions.

By the way, PDO is apparently not the way to go - it is ugly, toilsome to use and unsafe with whatever query that goes slightly beyond several basic cases.
For example:

```
// SafeMySQL: only 2 lines and not a sign of injection
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM goods WHERE category IN(?a) ORDER BY ?n";
$data = $db->getAll($sql, $_GET['categories'], $_GET['orderby']);

// PDO
// errr... (massive headscratching resulting with something like 
// 2 screens of code with manual escaping and all that stuff 
// but most likely still unsdafe as only few PHP developers
// actually have an idea how to properly handle such cases )
```

Comment: PDO is most certainly the way to go if your application needs to be compatible with various databases.  It depends on your needs.

Comment: Could you give examples on how PDO is "unsafe"?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something similar to a "database wrapper class".

PHP since 5.1 has a built-in abstraction layer called PDO for that.